# What is the blue box that the Exp. 53 Astronuats/Cosmonauts carried with them?

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight, spacesuits, identify-this-object, sokol-spacesuit

Looking at a video from Roscosmos on instagram, Exp. 52 Cosmonaut Sergey Ryazansky carried a blue box with him during his walk to the Soyuz rocket.

[image]

Upon looking at more videos of Astronauts boarding into rockets. I found [this video](https://youtu.be/YdyL-GVpWR4) of Apollo 10 Astronauts walking towards the rocket with similar looking boxes that they were each holding.

[image]

So what are these boxes that Astronauts/Cosmonauts carry into the rockets they board?

Comment: US astronauts carry a pack that provides cooling for their suits, IIRC. No idea if the Russian item is related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Sokol suits are provided with a ventilation unit for use prior to ingress into the spacecraft. "When worn on the ground, the suit is attached to a portable ventilation unit —a hand-held device that supplies air to the suit, cooling it first with an ice filled heat exchanger."

This is a training version of the unit.

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokol_space_suit)

Comment: Those look like they're built into pretty standard [Pelican](http://www.pelican.com)-style equipment cases. Are the non-training ones different?

Comment: @T.J.L. there seem to be a lot of versions of these.  The ones here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39526/what-are-these-soyuz-astronauts-cosmonauts-holding-in-their-hands-before-launch , the ones in the first picture in the question, and these training units all look different.